# Not able to save the record in using LWC code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

In Case object I have few fields. Using LWC I want to insert the value in the case record. Here is the code which I have.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input label="First Name" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Last Name" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Company" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Primary Phone" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Secondary Phone" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Email Address" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Subject" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Description" onchange={handleChangeCaseVal} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
        <lightning-button label="Submit" variant="brand" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
        </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';
import FIRST_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Case.First_Name__c';
import LAST_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Last_Name__c';
import COMPANY from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Company__c';
import EMAIL_ADDRESS from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Email_Address__c';
import PRIMARY_PHONE from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Primary_Phone__c';
import SECONDARY_PHONE from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Secondary_Phone__c';
import SUBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';
import DESCRIPTION from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Description';
import SaveCaseRec from '@salesforce/apex/CaseRoutingCls.SaveCaseRec';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';


export default class Webtocase extends LightningElement {
    varCaseId;
    @track FirstName =FIRST_NAME;
    @track LastName = LAST_NAME;
    @track CompanyName = COMPANY;
    @track EmailAdd = EMAIL_ADDRESS;
    @track PrimPhone = PRIMARY_PHONE;
    @track SecPhone = SECONDARY_PHONE;
    @track CaseSubject = SUBJECT;
    @track CaseDesc = DESCRIPTION;

    recCaseRec = {
        First_Name__c : this.FirstName,
        Last_Name__c : this.LastName,
        Company__c : this.CompanyName,
        Email_Address__c : this.EmailAdd,
        Primary_Phone__c : this.PrimPhone,
        Secondary_Phone__c : this.SecPhone,
        Subject : this.CaseSubject,
        Description : this.CaseDesc
    }

    handleChangeCaseVal(event) {
        console.log("########", event.target.label);
        if (event.target.label === 'First Name') {
            this.recCaseRec.FirstName = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Last Name') {
            this.recCaseRec.LastName = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Company') {
            this.recCaseRec.CompanyName = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Primary Phone') {
            this.recCaseRec.PrimPhone = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Secondary Phone') {
            this.recCaseRec.SecPhone = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Email Address') {
            this.recCaseRec.EmailAdd = event.target.value;
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Subject') {
            this.recCaseRec.CaseSubject = event.target.value;
            console.log("Subject", this.CaseSubject +'**** '+event.target.value);
        }
        if (event.target.label === 'Description') {
            this.recCaseRec.CaseDesc = event.target.value;
            console.log("Description", this.CaseDesc +'**** '+event.target.value);
        }
    }

    handleSuccess(event) {
        this.varCaseId = event.detail.id;
    }
    handleClick() {
        console.log("Final val",this.recCaseRec);
        SaveWebToCaseRec({ Cs : this.recCaseRec })
            .then(result => {
                this.message = result;
                this.error = undefined;
                if(this.message !== undefined) {
                    this.dispatchEvent(
                        new ShowToastEvent({
                            title: 'Success',
                            message: 'Case created',
                            variant: 'success',
                        }),
                    );
                }
                
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                console.log("result", this.message);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.message = undefined;
                this.error = error;
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error creating record',
                        message: error.body.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
                console.log("error", JSON.stringify(this.error));
            });
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void SaveCaseRec(Case Cs){
  try {
    insert cs;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

When I run this code I am getting following error:

> error {"status":500,"body":{"message":"Insert failed. First exception
> on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_ON_FIELD_IN_RECORD, Subject: value
> not of required type: {fieldApiName=Subject, objectApiName=Case}:
> [Subject]"},"headers":{}}

Can anyone point me what is the error with this code?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are not using `lightning-record-edit-form`?

Comment: You are not assigning all field values to `recCaseRec` and looks like the `Subject` is required, please set values to all fields just like you have done for the `FirstName` in `handleChangeCaseVal()`

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale I updated the code. Still I am seeing the same issue.

Comment: It's a type error meaning the field is not getting the type of expected response. Set the type of all the `lightning-input` fields and try again.